# Can't run the Python interpreter in Mac's Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, python

At the moment i'm on Mavericks, and i just uninstalled homebrew. With homebrew i had installed python, but after uninstalling it my terminal can't start the python interpreter.
I receive this message:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory`

There is some kind of configuration that i have to restore for execute the native version of python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting Terminal will probably do the trick.

Comment: It worked! To uninstall homebrew i've runned this file (https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223), is the correct way to remove it?

Comment: @g_rmz: Yeah, but your shell caches paths to executables for a period of time. Restarting it clears that.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: You could run `hash -r`, which would cause `bash` (your shell) to forget the locations of the executables, and "re-search" for them in `$PATH`.

More in-depth answer: By default, `bash` stores commands and their locations in a table (`hash`). It then only needs to search `$PATH` once per command, and search the table for each time you run the command again.
Restarting `bash` **will** clear the hash table, but if you don't want to restart it, `hash -r` (to clear the table) or `hash -p commandname` (to clear just one entry) will work.

Comment: So at this point i don't have to run hash -r, do i?

Comment: @g_rmz Correct. This is another way of doing the same thing. (But what if you had a bunch of environment variables and aliases set up for the session? Would you want to restart?)